# Writer vertically and break sentance after some specific height

Tags: jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BSSt.jpg)

```
<td class="yellow _BusinessLvl" attr_id="BusinessLevel">
    <div class="relative">
       <span id="busLvl_5T7V">ssdasdad sdadasd ssdasdad sdadasdssdasdad sdadasdssdasdad sdadasdssdasdad sdadasdssdasdad sdadasd
       </span>
       <a class="remove">X</a>
    </div>
</td>
```

## CSS

```
.relative {
    position: relative;
}
td span {
    transform-origin: 0 50%;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: -400px;
}
```

This is our HTML strucuture and CSS. what to make  that td in 2 line.

for more detail visit: https://jsfiddle.net/nilang_nil/r4cq9u64/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nbny1o5b/8/  i have updated css try this.